# Safe way for assigning a value for "const char*"

Tags: c++, char, initialization, constants

I am newbie in c++. In the following code, I call two methods, first `initialize` and then `connect`:

```
const char* str;

void initialize() {
    string temp = "blah blah";
    str= temp.c_str();
    cout << "str: " << str << endl; //prints: "str: blah blah"
    temp = "foo bar";
    cout << "str: " << str << endl; //prints: "str: foo bar"
}
```

I want to know why changing `temp` variable, causes `str` variable to change too and what is the best and **safe** way to set a value for `const char*`?

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: [Question 6441218](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) is not a duplicate of this at all. Reopen.